# Modal Value, and Repetition

Tags: arrays, vb.net, math

I want to make a modal value calculator, So it calculates the Modal value and its repetition

The idea is to make a list of data and its repetition like shown in any Graph.

This is code you I start with:

```
Public Class

Dim a1(100), a2(100), Rep(100), RepMer(100), AMer(100) As Single, n, count, m As Single, z, k, c, mars As Integer
    n = InputBox("How many data?", "RepTest")

    count = 0

    For count = 0 To n - 1
        a1(count) = InputBox("Add Value", "RepTest")
    Next

    z = n
    For run = 0 To n - 1
        mars = c
        z = z - 1
        k = 0
        For moon = 0 To (n - 1)

            If a1(z) = a1(moon) Then
                k = k + 1
                a2(run) = a1(z)
                Rep(run) = Rep(run) + k
                If Rep(run) > 2 Then
                    Rep(run) = Rep(run) - 1
                 End If

            End If
        Next

        MsgBox(a2(run)), , "Modal Value")
        MsgBox(Rep(run)),, "Repetition")

    Next

End Class
```

However, If you make the massage box outside the main 2nd loop, you have to make another loop with the same value 0 To (n-1), to match data position in an Array.

what I want you to help me please is:

I have to save the modal value and the repetition of one value in same position in the array, because if you use this code the output of n = 5 and enter value 2 ,2 ,2 ,1,1. the output will be 5 massage box with 3 equal for value 2, and 2 equal for value 1.

you can test by yourself copy the code and insert it to a form in VB.net.

---

With pictures:

see this link: [Picture that describe  the result](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/654645)

You can see that the output is more than one for each value, so How can I store the value and its repetition in one position in an array?

---

Thank you for reading, please I want a code answer. :)

Comment: At first glance, you have major problems in the code. First of all, your class has no name - you should get a compiler error. In addition, you are executing code ouside a method or a function. You can't do that.

Comment: No, I post this to you, to make you copy the code between the class.

Comment: but it all work with out errors as you show in picture.

Comment: I don't ask you about the errors, I ask you: how can I change this code to output one value each repetition and its value. So what is the best alogarithms that I have to use to output the modal value and its repetition in one position in an array. (the code is what could I do, but if you can create another code that can calculate modal value of data and their repetition, go a head!).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
If you want count duplicates(repetitions) of values and then use it for your needs:

- Create custom class where you can keep information about value and amount of repetitions

```vb
Public Class RepetitionValue
    Public Property Value As Single
    Public Property RepetitionAmount As Int32

    Public Sub New(value As Single)
        Me.Value = value
        Me.RepetitionAmount = 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

- Collect values and count duplicates, save it in then `Directory` collection
  With Directory you will easy get object by value
- Use collection for manipulating data

```vb
Public Sub YourSybName()
    Dim values As New List(Of Single)()
    Dim numberOfData As Int32 
    numberOfData = Int32.Parse(InputBox("How many data?", "RepTest"))
    For count As Int32 = 0 To numberOfData - 1
        values.Add(InputBox("Add Value", "RepTest"))
    Next
    Dim modals As New Dictionary(Of Single, RepetitionValue)()
    For Each value As Single In values
        If modals.ContainsKey(value) = True Then
            modals(value).RepetitionAmount += 1
        Else
            modals.Add(New RepetitionAmount(value))
        End If
    Next
    'Use collection for your needs 
    'For example if I have 5 data, then I enter 1 . 5 . 1 . 2 . 1. 
    'then I want to divide repetition of value 1 by repetition of value 5. 

    Dim valueOf1 As RepetitionValue = modals(1)
    Dim valueOf5 As RepetiotionValue = modals(5)
    Dim divideResult As Decimal = valueOf1.RepetitionAmount/valueOf5.RepetitionAmount
End Public
```

Comment: But you see there is a problem, that I want for example I want value 2 to show how many does it repeat in the data the output give value 2 for each repetition, I don't want this I want the program to say the modal value 2 repeated 5 times for example, and then continue to another number or value. Thank you for your response:)

Comment: Thank you, :) it's work. But I want to reuse the output data in something, can you help me with that. so I want to know which variables store the value and which value store the repetition, to use it to make graph that show the value and its repetition.

Comment: Can you explain it more, please. for example if I have 5 data, then I enter 1 . 5 . 1 . 2 . 1. then I want to divide repetition of value 1 by repetition of value 5. what could I do? thank you, reply soon:)

Comment: one more thing, these code should I insert it to a form, or vb code file?

Comment: Doesn't matter where you put code, It can be in Form or in the own file

Comment: Actually I didn't understand the code very well. Can you please answer the previous comment that I posted.